# Accidently made a Admin account and forgot password

Tags: windows, passwords, password-hash

I am on Windows 11 and made a Admin account along with an account with low perms. Forgot the admin pass but can still get into the low perm one. Is there a way to crack the admin password without losing data on either account?

Tried Finding hash to crack with hashcat but couldnt gain access to the hash